# SharePoint 2013. JSLink (CSR) for field Type="User" on EditForm

Tags: 2013, javascript, people-picker, jslink

How to create custorm render for field type="User" on EditForm? I need to replace standart peoplePicker control with my custom render.

Code below work without exeptions, but don't set 'Sponsor' field.

```
var ctx = {};
ctx.Templates = {};
ctx.Templates.Fields = {
    'Sponsor': {
        'EditForm': function (ctx) {
            var formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);
            formCtx.registerGetValueCallback(formCtx.fieldName, function () {

                // Looks like the problem here
                return '[{"Key":"i:0#.w|dev\\administrator","Description":"DEV\\administrator","DisplayText":"DEV\\administrator","EntityType":"User","ProviderDisplayName":"Active Directory","ProviderName":"AD","IsResolved":true,"EntityData":{"Title":"","MobilePhone":"","SIPAddress":"","Department":"","Email":""},"MultipleMatches":[],"AutoFillKey":"i:0#.w|dev\\administrator","AutoFillDisplayText":"DEV\\administrator","AutoFillSubDisplayText":"","AutoFillTitleText":"Active Directory\nDEV\\administrator","DomainText":"dev12","Resolved":true,"LocalSearchTerm":"adm"}]';

            });

            return '<div>MY_PEOPLEPICKER</div>';
        }
    }
};
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);
```

registerGetValueCallback function return string that I take from EditForm submit request (I use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) tool).

Returning string "1;#administrator" didn't help too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The working code (etension on slashes):

```
var ctx = {};
ctx.Templates = {};
ctx.Templates.Fields = {
    'Sponsor': {
        'EditForm': function (ctx) {
            var formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);
            formCtx.registerGetValueCallback(formCtx.fieldName, function () {
                return '[{"Key":"i:0#.w|dev\\\\administrator","Description":"DEV\\\\administrator","DisplayText":"DEV\\\\administrator","EntityType":"User","ProviderDisplayName":"Active Directory","ProviderName":"AD","IsResolved":true,"EntityData":{"Title":"","MobilePhone":"","SIPAddress":"","Department":"","Email":""},"MultipleMatches":[],"AutoFillKey":"i:0#.w|dev\\\\administrator","AutoFillDisplayText":"DEV\\\\administrator","AutoFillSubDisplayText":"","AutoFillTitleText":"Active Directory\\nDEV\\\\administrator","DomainText":"dev12","Resolved":true,"LocalSearchTerm":"adm"}]';
            });

            return '<div>MY_PEOPLEPICKER</div>';
        }
    }
};
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);
```