# Unable to return value of Person or Group field from JSLink

Tags: 2013, jslink, client-side-rendering, newform

I have a custom list in which I have applied JSLink on Person/Group field in `NewForm.aspx`, my code works fine to render the field but when I click on submit button, I am returning value. `<userId>;#<LoginName>` to SharePoint in statement like below:

```
formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);
formCtx.registerGetValueCallback(formCtx.fieldName, function () {
return "1;#xxx yyy;";
});
```

But I am not getting any value stored after the item is saved.

How do I return the value to Person field?

Note : The field is single allow value.

Comment: is this a claims web application? Have you provided the claims token? Also, what's the health of your user profile service? Can you find the username in question on the user profile service?

Comment: It is windows authentication web application. So, I tried to return value using, `i:<userId>#.w|<domain>\<userLoginName>`, but still not working.

Answer (score 4):

After searching for the issue for hours I found a solution which returns the data to SharePoint for Person or Group field.

Thanks to author of [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89579/sharepoint-2013-jslink-csr-for-field-type-user-on-editform) post. From this post , I got the idea.

However in my case the only string to return to SharePoint is `[{"Key":"i:<id>#.w|domain\\\\<UserLoginName>"}]`.

So, finally my piece of code to submit data from JSLink is:

```
formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);
formCtx.registerGetValueCallback(formCtx.fieldName, function () {
// return '[{"Key":"i:0#.w|bitscape\\\\riyaz.kalva","EntityType":"User","IsResolved":true}]';
return '[{"Key":"i:0#.w|domain\\\\xxx.yyy"}]';
});
```

Thanks,

Hope this helps others too.!!!